# Spark + Scala: How to add external dependencies in build.sbt

Tags: scala, apache-spark, sbt, spark-streaming

I'm new to Spark (using v2.4.5), and am still trying to figure out the correct way to add external dependencies. When trying to add Kafka streaming to my project, my `build.sbt` looked liked this:

```
name := "Stream Handler"

version := "1.0"

scalaVersion := "2.11.12"

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
    "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % "2.4.5" % "provided",  
    "org.apache.spark" % "spark-streaming_2.11" % "2.4.5" % "provided",
    "org.apache.spark" % "spark-streaming-kafka-0-10_2.11" % "2.4.5"
)
```

This builds successfully, but when running with `spark-submit`, I get a `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError` with `KafkaUtils`.

I was able to get my code working by passing in the dependency thru the `--packages` option like this:

```
$ spark-submit [other_args] --packages "org.apache.spark:org.apache.spark:spark-streaming-kafka-0-10_2.11:2.4.5"
```

Ideally I would like to set up all the dependencies in the `build.sbt`, but I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. Any advice would be appreciated!

Comment: the documentation says spark-core should be used defined as `spark-core_2.11`

https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.0/streaming-kafka-0-10-integration.html#deploying

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your     `"org.apache.spark" % "spark-streaming-kafka-0-10_2.11" % "2.4.5"` is wrong.

change that  to below like mvnrepo.. https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.spark/spark-streaming-kafka-0-10

```
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-streaming-kafka-0-10" % "2.4.5"
```